# DB2 create view with common table expression

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, db2-luw

Hey I exported a view definition from DB2 on AS400 and want to import it into DB2 LUW express-c, but I keep getting syntax errors whenever I try to use a `WITH` clause:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=AS;MAATNUMMER, AANTAL)
>   ;JOIN, DRIVER=4.19.77

If I execute the query in DB2 on AS400 it works and according to IBM's documentation express-c should support common table expressions.

If anyone could have a look at it and point me in the right direction

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWRTSGEPLAND (
    LOCATIE3,
    LOCATIE4,
    DISKNR,
    MAAT,
    MAATNUM,
    SKU,
    AANTAL,
    SOORT,
    BRON,
    DATUM,
    VOLGNR,
    STATUS,
    GEBRUIKER,
    PROGRAMMA,
    KBNUMMER,
    STATUSKB,
    "TIMESTAMP")
  AS(
      WITH 
        SEL1TF (TFLKNA, TFDSNR, TFMBKD, MAATNUMMER, AANTAL) AS (
        -- selectie op TF +  cross join NOS002 om 1 row per maat te bekomen
        SELECT TF.TFLKNA, TF.TFDSNR, TF.TFMBKD, NOS002.MAATNUMMER,
               SUM(TF.TFTA01 * NOS002.M01 + TF.TFTA02 * NOS002.M02 + 
                   TF.TFTA03 * NOS002.M03 + TF.TFTA04 * NOS002.M04 +
                   TF.TFTA05 * NOS002.M05 + TF.TFTA06 * NOS002.M06 +
                   TF.TFTA07 * NOS002.M07 + TF.TFTA08 * NOS002.M08 +
                   TF.TFTA09 * NOS002.M09 + TF.TFTA10 * NOS002.M10 + 
                   TF.TFTA11 * NOS002.M11 + TF.TFTA12 * NOS002.M12 +
                   TF.TFTA13 * NOS002.M13 + TF.TFTA14 * NOS002.M14 + 
                   TF.TFTA15 * NOS002.M15 + TF.TFTA16 * NOS002.M16) AS AANTAL
            FROM LFILES.TF TF
            CROSS JOIN AJR.NOS002 NOS002
            -- geen where, ook niet op de winkel 37 - 28
            GROUP BY TF.TFLKNA, TF.TFDSNR, TF.TFMBKD, NOS002.MAATNUMMER
        ), 
        SELTF (TFLKNA, TFDSNR, TFMBKD, MAATNUMMER, AANTAL) AS (
        -- eliminatie van de groepen die 0 zijn nu pas voor de leesbaarheid +
        -- geen 2x schrijven van de berekening
        SELECT SEL1TF.TFLKNA, SEL1TF.TFDSNR, SEL1TF.TFMBKD,
               SEL1TF.MAATNUMMER, SEL1TF.AANTAL
            FROM SEL1TF SEL1TF
            WHERE SEL1TF.AANTAL <> 0
        )
    -- main select
    SELECT E5XT.E5XTLKNR AS LOCATIE3, 
           E5XT.E5XTLKKD AS LOCATIE4, 
           SELTF.TFDSNR AS DISKNR, 
           NOS001.MAATOMSCHR AS MAAT, 
           NOS001.MAATNUM AS MAATNUM, 
           CAST((DIGITS(SELTF.TFDSNR) CONCAT '.' CONCAT DIGITS(NOS001.MAATNUM)) AS CHAR(11)) AS SKU, 
           CAST(SELTF.AANTAL AS DEC(6, 0)) AS AANTAL, 
           CAST('GEPLAND IN' AS CHAR(20)) AS SOORT, 
           CAST('power.LFILES.TF' AS CHAR(30)) AS BRON, 
           CURRENT_DATE AS DATUM, 
           CAST(0 AS DEC(9, 0)) AS VOLGNR, 
           CAST(SPACE(1) AS CHAR(1)) AS STATUS, 
           CAST(SPACE(10) AS CHAR(10)) AS GEBRUIKER, 
           CAST(SPACE(10) AS CHAR(10)) AS PROGRAMMA, 
           CAST(0 AS DEC(9, 0)) AS KBNUMMER, 
           CAST(SPACE(2) AS CHAR(2)) AS STATUSKB, 
           CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP
      FROM SELTF SELTF
        INNER JOIN LFILES.E5XT E5XT
          ON SELTF.TFLKNA = E5XT.E5XTLKNR
        INNER JOIN AJR.NOS001 NOS001
          ON SELTF.TFMBKD = NOS001.MSMBKD
          AND SELTF.MAATNUMMER = NOS001.MAATNUMMER
);
```

Comment: We are going to need more information about the error. All you are telling us is that there is a syntax error. That's pretty generic. DB2-LUW at least as recent as 9.5 supports CTE's. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 10.5.0.5-3.10.0, I would love to give you more information, but the only feedback I get is the error above, I get a slightly more descriptive error when I execute the sql through my IDE(IntelliJ) 
`[42601][-104] An unexpected token "AS" was found following "( WITH RTSI2SEL ". Expected tokens may include: "JOIN".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.23.42`

Comment: Is there a 80 column limit in LUW express-c?  I have gotten unexpected syntax errors like that on the IBM i because some programs will accept only 80 character SQL while other programs will accept it wider.  Easy to check given SQL's acceptance of whitespace:  just add some carriage returns to test this speculation.  I see you have some places 94 columns wide.

Comment: I just tested it and no 80 column limit

Comment: "TIMESTAMP"  Consider as "Order Timestamp"  or ORDTIMESAMP the quotes with spaces add complexity but makes for a quick easy column headings.

Comment: I can't change the choosen names, there are a lot of programs that are using this view currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the extra brackets after the first AS. I.e. this parses fine in DataStudio, so if I had the table DDL, I'm sure it would create OK.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWRTSGEPLAND (
    LOCATIE3,
    LOCATIE4,
    DISKNR,
    MAAT,
    MAATNUM,
    SKU,
    AANTAL,
    SOORT,
    BRON,
    DATUM,
    VOLGNR,
    STATUS,
    GEBRUIKER,
    PROGRAMMA,
    KBNUMMER,
    STATUSKB,
    "TIMESTAMP")
  AS
    --(   <<<<< REMOVE THIS BRACKET 
WITH SEL1TF (TFLKNA, TFDSNR, TFMBKD, MAATNUMMER, AANTAL)
        AS (
            -- selectie op TF +  cross join NOS002 om 1 row per maat te bekomen
            SELECT TF.TFLKNA, TF.TFDSNR, TF.TFMBKD, NOS002.MAATNUMMER, SUM(TF.TFTA01 * NOS002.M01 + TF.TFTA02 * NOS002.M02 + TF.TFTA03 * NOS002.M03
            + TF.TFTA04 * NOS002.M04 + TF.TFTA05 * NOS002.M05 + TF.TFTA06 * NOS002.M06
            + TF.TFTA07 * NOS002.M07 + TF.TFTA08 * NOS002.M08 + TF.TFTA09 * NOS002.M09
            + TF.TFTA10 * NOS002.M10 + TF.TFTA11 * NOS002.M11 + TF.TFTA12 * NOS002.M12
            + TF.TFTA13 * NOS002.M13 + TF.TFTA14 * NOS002.M14 + TF.TFTA15 * NOS002.M15
            + TF.TFTA16 * NOS002.M16) AS AANTAL
                FROM LFILES.TF TF
                CROSS JOIN AJR.NOS002 NOS002
                -- geen where, ook niet op de winkel 37 - 28
                GROUP BY TF.TFLKNA, TF.TFDSNR, TF.TFMBKD, NOS002.MAATNUMMER
            ), 
        SELTF (TFLKNA, TFDSNR, TFMBKD, MAATNUMMER, AANTAL)
          AS (
            -- eliminatie van de groepen die 0 zijn nu pas voor de leesbaarheid +
            -- geen 2x schrijven van de berekening
            SELECT SEL1TF.TFLKNA, SEL1TF.TFDSNR, SEL1TF.TFMBKD, SEL1TF.MAATNUMMER, SEL1TF.AANTAL
            FROM SEL1TF SEL1TF
            WHERE SEL1TF.AANTAL <> 0
          )
        -- main select
        SELECT
        E5XT.E5XTLKNR AS LOCATIE3, E5XT.E5XTLKKD AS LOCATIE4, SELTF.TFDSNR AS DISKNR, NOS001.MAATOMSCHR AS MAAT, NOS001.MAATNUM AS MAATNUM, CAST((DIGITS(SELTF.TFDSNR) CONCAT '.' CONCAT DIGITS(NOS001.MAATNUM))
        AS CHAR(11)) AS SKU, CAST(SELTF.AANTAL AS DEC(6, 0)) AS AANTAL, CAST('GEPLAND IN' AS CHAR(20)) AS SOORT, CAST('power.LFILES.TF' AS CHAR(30)) AS BRON, CURRENT_DATE AS DATUM, CAST(0 AS DEC(9, 0)) AS VOLGNR, CAST(SPACE(1) AS CHAR(1)) AS STATUS, CAST(SPACE(10) AS CHAR(10)) AS GEBRUIKER, CAST(SPACE(10) AS CHAR(10)) AS PROGRAMMA, CAST(0 AS DEC(9, 0)) AS KBNUMMER, CAST(SPACE(2) AS CHAR(2)) AS STATUSKB, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP
        FROM SELTF SELTF
        INNER JOIN LFILES.E5XT E5XT
        ON SELTF.TFLKNA = E5XT.E5XTLKNR
        INNER JOIN AJR.NOS001 NOS001
        ON SELTF.TFMBKD = NOS001.MSMBKD
        AND SELTF.MAATNUMMER = NOS001.MAATNUMMER
--)  <<<<< REMOVE THIS BRACKET
;
```

Comment: IBM Data Studio is not everyone's favorite SQL IDE, but it does have the advantage of full, local parsing of Db2 SQL, so it can help identify where syntax errors are better than the error message you get back from the Db2 engine.